# Angular google map get latitude and longitude center of the map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

From [Angular-Google Map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) perspective using a controller how can i get the (longitude and latitude) center of the current map if like say my controller looks like this:

```
$scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: $scope.latitude,
        longitude: $scope.longitude
      },
      zoom: 7,
      bounds: {},
      control: {},
    };


 var map = self.map.control.getGMap();
        var maps = google.maps;
        this.registerMap = function (myMap) {
          var center = myMap.getCenter(),
            latitude = center.lat(),
            longitude = center.lng();
            map = myMap;
            $scope.latitude = latitude;
            $scope.longitude = longitude;
            $log.info(latitude+"  "+longitude);
            return;
            };
$scope.$watch('$scope.map.center', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) { 
                   $log.info("value change");
                  var center = map.getCenter(),
                  latitude = center.lat(),
                  longitude = center.lng();
                  if ($scope.latitude !== latitude || $scope.longitude !== longitude)
                      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.latitude, $scope.longitude));
                }
              });
```

As i saw at these nice tutorial http://wbyoko.co/angularjs/angularjs-google-maps-components.html
and http://dylanfprice.github.io/angular-gm/1.0.0/examples/#!/map/

but these wont work on angular google map cause of different library and approach

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

For google maps api v3(javascript) there is a function called getCenter() which returns the latlng of the center of map.[**reference doc**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).
Maybe you can try calling this function using the angular-google-maps since it's based on the maps api anyway.

Comment: I already try this 2 days ago and seem it not work, prefer code examples so i can learn their syntax. seem angular google map syntax have their unix way to implement google map code